# Angular 2 RxJS Observable not loading

Tags: angular, rxjs

my web application breaks (won't load) when I use 'new Observable()' anywhere in a method or otherwise.

```
Angular version 2.1.0
RxJs 5.0.0-beta.12
```

These are my imports in the .ts-file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DSUnit } from '../model/dsunit';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { DSCategory } from './../model/dscategory';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

When I have this piece of code it breaks:

```
private handleError(error: any) : Observable<any> {
    let errMsg = "argh";
    return new Observable(); // <-- "offending" code
}
```

with this error on the console of Chrome:

```
(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs(…)
```

And when I remove the offending line, and have this instead:

```
private handleError(error: any) : Observable<any> {
    let errMsg = "argh";
    return null; // <-- "works" 
}
```

my web application loads with no errors.. of course it breaks when the 'catch'-statement tries to handle an error, but that will work once I get past the hurdle with

```
"new Observable()"
```

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';` This caught me out as well...

Comment: Sometimes you just can't trust your IDE when one's using the auto import feature....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn it... the 'auto import' in Visual Studio Code had messed up my import.

When I import '{Observable}' it should not be

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'
```

it should be

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
Observable.of(errMsg);
```

or

```
Observable.throw(errMsg);
```

depending on the caller.

Comment: It doesn't work. The thing is that ANY use of Observable that will create an Observable-object will break.

I initially tried Observable.throw but that broke, so I tried to return just a plain Observable object, which also breaks. Same goes when I try to use Observable.of()....